# variable assignment is not working in rhel6 linux

Tags: linux, shell

file1

```
ABY37499|ANK37528|DEL37508|SRILANKA|195203230000|445500759
ARJU7499|CHA38008|DEL37508|SRILANKA|195203230000|445500759
IB1704174|ANK37528|DEL37508|SRILANKA|195203230000|445500759
IB1704174|CHA38008|DEL37508|SRILANKA|195203230000|445500759
ABY37500|ANK37529|DEL37509|BRAZIL|195203240000|445500757
ARJU7500|CHA38009|DEL37509|BRAZIL|195203240000|445500757
IB1704175|ANK37529|DEL37509|BRAZIL|195203240000|445500757
```

i want to convert the fifth column date to another format script below

```
#!/bin/sh
dt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
awk -F '|' '{print $5}' file1 | sed 's/.\{8\}/& /g'> f1.txt
aa=`(date -f f1.txt +"$dt")`
echo "$aa"
awk -F '|' '$5=$aa' file1
```

---

echo "$aa" got desired output but i cannot assign $aa to $5 please help me.
Thanks

Comment: If with $5 you mean the 5-th fields read by awk, then you can't assign a value to it. What you want to achieve?

Comment: The formatting  was not good, so I formatted the code to make it look clean and clear.

Comment: Hello Thanks for the reply i want to substitute 5th column date to desired date format that is : 195203240000 to ("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") in file1

Comment: Hello in file1 column 5 is date i want change that date to this date format ("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") ie 195203240000 to 1952-03-23 00:00. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I corrected my answer after the commento of Etan Reisner

---

from AWK man:

> The input is read in units called records, and processed by the rules
>   of your program one record at a time. By default, each record is one
>   line. Each record is automatically split into chunks called fields.
>   This makes it more convenient for programs to work on the parts of a
>   record.

Fields are stored in variables `$1, $2, ...`

And

> The contents of a field, as seen by awk, can be changed within an awk
>   program; this changes what awk perceives as the current input record.

see the man [page](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Changing-Fields.html)

thus, this expression:

```
awk -F '|' '$5=$aa' file1
```

does not have the effect of substitute the fifth column of **file1**.

You have to write the modified output to a second file.

Comment: Ok, if you don't mind please  show me how to use sed for my requirement.Thanks

Comment: @Ben See my answer on sed

Comment: You absolutely **can** assign to `$5`. It just won't edit the file in place. It will only modify the representation of the line in awk. You can write the modified output to a second file though.

Comment: @EtanReisner OMG! You are absolutely right. I didn't know it and I (wrongly) assumed that you couldn't. Don't know what to do, I update the answer but maybe is better to delete it?

Comment: Newer versions of GNU awk (4.1.0+) even have an in-place option (like sed).

Answer (score 0):

May be this could help you in `sed`

`echo 195203240000 | sed -n -e "s_\(....\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)_\1-\2-\3 \4:\5_p"`

`1952-03-24 00:00`

Comment: Thank you realspirituals.But my actual requirement is i have one file named file1 it has six columns and lacks of raws, its fifth column is date ie 195203240000 i want to change this 5th column to corresponding date format ie 1952-03-23 00:00 file1 listed above.How can i achieve this? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This awk script should do what you want.

It isn't exactly pretty but it works assuming the input format is consistent.

```
awk '{$5=sprintf("%s-%s-%s %s:%s\n",
      substr($5,1,4), substr($5,5,2), substr($5,7,2),
      substr($5,9,2), substr($5,11,2))} 7' file1 > file1.new
```

It assigns the new value for the field to `$5` and then uses `7` (as a truth-y value) to get the default awk `{print}` action to print the modified line.

Comment: Hai Etan i run the script it shows syntax error  awk: {$5=sprintf "%s-%s-%s %s:%s\n", substr($5,1,4), substr($5,5,2), substr($5,7,2), substr($5,9,2), substr($5,11,2)} 7
awk:             ^ syntax error                Thank you.

Comment: @Ben Sorry, fixed the formatting. I'd been testing with `printf` but `sprintf` is a function call.